# Set minRange in Highcharts at week, but doesn't work

Tags: highcharts

i have a problem with **minRange**

My chart is "time series, zoomable" type (i enabled also scrollbar for x-axis). 
I would like to have minRange weekly when i zoom the chart, but doesn't work...

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/rax26mvb/`
```

why ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minRange define maximum zoom level, when you zoom by selection. In your case you need to also define min/max values on xAxis.